# How can I pass an entire array to a function while utilizing multiprocessing to pass each row of a pandas dataframe separately?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have multiprocessing working where I can send each row of my dataframe separately in pools, but I want to send an array variable in its entirety to be used in the function. When I try to add it in as is it seems to split each item from the array just like it is doing to the dataframe. When I hardcode the array inside the function it works just fine, but I want to dynamically create an array before the multiprocessing starts so it doesn't happen every time the function runs.

My code that throws an error because the length of the df doesn't match the length of the array

```py
import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

def function(name, array):
    x = []
    for i in array:
        if name == i:
            x.append(True)
        else:
            x.append(False)
    if any(item == True for item in x):
        return True
    return False

def main():
    data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['john', 16], ['rick', 12], ['randal', 11]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age']) 

    array = ['bill', 'nick', 'randal', 'chris']


    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
        df["result"] = list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.map(function, df["name"], array, chunksize=4), 
        total=df.shape[0]))

    print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In my heavy pandas use over the past few years, I've *rarely* found the need to use multiprocessing, because in general, most pandas operations should **not** act row-wise as there are vectorized solutions available. From the looks of it, this seems like you want to check if a name is in some list, which can be done efficiently and in as few characters as `df['result'] = df['name'].isin(array)`.

Comment: @ALollz The main reason I incorporated multiprocessing is because I have a very large dataset, so having multiple running at once is a huge time saver for me. I also have several other functions related to image processing that run when I am doing multiprocessing, so I don't think I can eliminate it entirely without increasing my processing time by a good amount. I could probably simplify the code in the function as you mentioned though.